# How to combine two simultaneously changing attribute history tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, teradata

I have two tables which track different sets of attribute histories for the same objects. The tables might look like this:

```
T1:
ID    | VERSION_ST    | VERSION_END | Attr1 
-----------------------------------------------
1     | 2012-01-01    | 2013-05-07  | Red
1     | 2013-05-08    | 2014-04-01  | Blue
1     | 2014-04-02    | NULL        | Green

T2:
ID    | VERSION_ST    | VERSION_END | Attr2 
-----------------------------------------------
1     | 2012-01-01    | 2013-06-04  | Large
1     | 2013-06-05    | 2014-07-15  | Medium
1     | 2014-07-16    | NULL        | Large
```

How can I write a query that will combine these attribute histories together such that I can see an accurate version start and end for both attributes?

The result set might look like this:

```
ID    | VERSION_ST    | VERSION_END | Attr1    | Attr2   
-----------------------------------------------------------
1     | 2012-01-01    | 2013-05-07  | Red      | Large
1     | 2013-05-08    | 2013-06-04  | Blue     | Large    
1     | 2013-06-05    | 2014-04-01  | Blue     | Medium    
1     | 2014-04-02    | 2014-07-15  | Green    | Medium        
1     | 2014-07-16    | NULL        | Green    | Large
```

When I try to join with `on T1.ID = T2.ID and T1.START between T2.START and T2.END`, there are only three rows returned, so its not accurately tracking the changes in T2. Same if I reverse it. Not sure how to do both at the same time.

I have access to a variety of database systems to do this work in, if *any* of them have this functionality I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you want to do is possible, the only real relationship between the two tables is your ID column.  Also, please flag your post with the correct RDBMS.

Comment: The specific RDBMS isn't really important to the answer is is? Just trying to get some exposure.

Comment: What kind of join are you using? Since you want a full table return from both tables where the ID's match, you may have union the two tables

Comment: The RDBMS would be important if it's a provider specific function that makes it possible.  What works in SQL Server 2012 may not have a counterpart in mySQL.

Comment: But I can really use any database system. Hence the list. Can any of them do it?

Comment: Preferably, `VERSION_END` should hold the same value as the next `VALUE_START` - the ending value is actually derived information.  It's actually a philosophical issue;  something is in one state until it's changed to the new one.  Your current dataset implies that there's a period of 24 hours where an id may have _no_ state.  Depending on the exact types chosen in a particular RDBMS, querying inclusive ranges is [problematic/difficult/gives wrong results](http://tiny.cc/fs21gx).  If you try to query this with a timestamp, you'd need to convert it first.

Comment: VERSION_START should never be the same as VERSION_END, or you would violate the Type-2 pattern if that exact timestamp was used in a BETWEEN statement, you would return both rows.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your example data, but there might be some cases where it will fail:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN t1.version_st < t2.version_st THEN t2.version_st ELSE t1.version_st END,
   CASE WHEN t1.version_end < t2.version_end THEN t1.version_end ELSE t2.version_end END,
   t1.attr1,
   t2.attr2
FROM t1 JOIN t2 
  ON T1.ID = T2.ID
 AND (t1.VERSION_ST, COALESCE(t1.VERSION_END, DATE '9999-12-31')) OVERLAPS
     (t2.VERSION_ST, COALESCE(t2.VERSION_END, DATE '9999-12-31'))
```

Edit:
OVERLAPS is supported by Teradata (most DBMSes don't know it), but can be replaced by:

```
FROM t1 JOIN t2 
  ON T1.ID = T2.ID
 AND t1.version_st < COALESCE(t2.version_end, DATE '9999-12-31')
 AND t2.version_st < COALESCE(t1.version_end, DATE '9999-12-31')
```

Answer (score 0):

What ever you tried is right because when you look into the output the  row 3  **Blue | Medium** is not possible because the Version_st of blue in table 1 doesn`t fall between the specified range.
You will get an output of 4 records if you try using the '**ISNULL(T2.End,'9999-12-31')** assuming null means its active. 
If it is oracle use NVL function.

Comment: Blue | Medium appears to be valid - table 1 changed the color to blue on May 8th 2013, table 2 was still set as large until June 4th 2013 when it changed to medium?

Comment: Yes. The fact that the time periods overlap is what causes the difficulty

Answer (score 0):

```
on T1.ID = T2.ID and T1.START between T2.START and T2.END
```

doesn't work by itself because the end of T1 could fall between the start/end of T2.

Try:

```
on T1.ID = T2.ID and (T1.START between T2.START and T2.END or T1.END between T2.START and T2.END)
```

To handle nulls, use COALLESCE(date, CURRENT_DATE) so that we consider anything with a null date to continue up to today.  In Oracle, current_date is SYSDATE, in Sql Server it is GETDATE().

Comment: This will still only return the value in T2 that was effective at the end or the beginning of the record in T1. If T2 changes several times between changes in T1, those changes except the first and last will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you what you need:

```
select
t1.version_st as t1_start,
t1.version_end as t1_end,
t2.version_st as t2_start,
t2.version_end as t2_end,
t1.attr1,
t2.attr2
from
t1
full join t2
on T1.ID = T2.ID and 
((T1.version_st between T2.version_st and T2.version_end )
 or (T1.version_END between T2.version_st and T2.version_end))
```

You need the full join, I think, because there is no guarantee the dates will line up (as in the last row in t2).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5409/15)

Comment: This creates two columns of version start and end dates. How would I consolidate that back into a single list of start and end dates?

Comment: Which one do you want?

Comment: To explain that more, its not possible to tell which start/end pair represents the actual start/end date, it is either min(T1, T2) or max(T1, T2) but its different for each row and I don't know how to tell which.

Comment: I think this will do it for your start date: `case when (t1.version_st <= t2.version_st) then t1.version_st else t2.version_st end`.  If that works, you can twist it around for your end date easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 a
INNER JOIN t2 b
on a.id = b.id and a.VERSION_ST between b.VERSION_ST and b.VERSION_END

UNION

SELECT * FROM t2 a
INNER JOIN t1 b
on a.id = b.id and a.VERSION_ST between b.VERSION_ST and b.VERSION_END
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5409/25

Comment: This seems to mix up the ATTR1 and ATTR2 values. Also, it needs to satisfy the condition that only one record is valid for any given date to be an attribute history table.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a dependency between one column of a row to a different column in a different row, you create what I call a Row Spanning Dependency. In your case, the dependency is between VERSION_END of one row and VERSION_ST of the next row in the sequence. This makes for very difficult DML and lots of data integrity headaches. In addition, you use the two date fields in different contexts even within the same row. That is, the effective duration of a row starts at midnight of the morning of VERSION_ST ('yyy-mm-dd 00:00:00') to the very last tick before midnight of the evening of VERSION_END ('yyy-mm-dd 23:59:59'). This leads to confusion if nothing else.

Fortunately, this is all solved by simply removing VERSION_END. It is not needed. The effective duration of a row begins at the date in VERSION_ST and remains in effect until the VERSION_ST of the next row. The "current" row is the one with no next row.

Notice the query below gives you the output you want and doesn't use VERSION_END at all. The first query returns the date Attr1 was created/updated along with the value of Attr2 at that time. The second query returns the date Attr2 was created/updated along with the value of Attr1 at that time. The `union` removes duplicate rows (Attr1 and Attr2 were both created at the same time so will appear in both queries).

```
select t1.id, t1.VERSION_ST, t1.Attr1, t2.Attr2
from   t1
left join t2
  on   t2.id = t1.id
  and  t2.VERSION_ST =(
        select max( VERSION_ST )
        from   t2
        where  VERSION_ST <= t1.VERSION_ST )
union
select t2.id, t2.VERSION_ST, t1.Attr1, t2.Attr2
from   t2
left join t1
  on   t1.id = t2.id
  and  t1.VERSION_ST =(
        select max( VERSION_ST )
        from   t1
        where  VERSION_ST <= t2.VERSION_ST );
```